# Single Click Binding to NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I am looking for some pointers on how to implement binding for a single click (similar to what NSTableView already has for Double Click on a row).  Initially I thought, it is much simpler to leverage selectionIndexes property and make use of that.  However when the table view gets loaded the value of this property corresponds to the zeroth index(first row) and it makes to think that the first row is always selected.  Please note that I do not want to use the option of setting delegate/datasource for the tableview and use the available methods there.

Comment: Binding `selectionIndexes` to a property and use the `didSet` observer is the usual way. Set an initial value of an empty `NSIndexSet` to that property and set the table view to allow empty selection.

Comment: @Vadian  I did try that option earlier and it still showed the index value to be  of zero.

Comment: Make sure that the table view and the array controller allow empty selection.

Comment: @Vadian.   Thanks a lot.  For some reason I was focusing only on the Table View and not on the Array Controller(so stupid of me).